# Crystal reports with not in function and inner select

Tags: crystal-reports

my question is i have this query and im planning to do a report from this. my problem is how do i do the not in from the inner select of the report?

```
   select prop_acct_no,land_book_value, impr_Book_value,current_book_value,lat_appr from prop_acct 
    where
    PROP_ACCT.PROP_STATUS = 'CON' and 
    PROP_ACCT.SUBSTATUS in ('AFS', 'FAS') and
    PROP_ACCT.IL_STATUS ='N' and 
    PROP_ACCT.PROP_ACCT_NO  not in 
    (select PROP_ACCT_NO from SP_DETL, SP_MAST where SP_DETL.SP_NO = SP_MAST.SP_NO and STATUS = 'Approved')
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a view/stored procedure out of that query and have crystal use that view/stored procedure. It's better to use stored procedure. It's difficult to write complicated query in crystal from my experience working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Add Command to Report option (found in the connection folder for an active Database Files or ODBC data source) to add your query to the report.